# Setup (https) SSL on localhost for meteor development

Tags: node.js, ssl, cookies, meteor, ssl-certificate

How do you create a self signed SSL certificate to use on local server on mac 10.9?

I require my localhost serving as `https://localhost`

I am using the linkedin API. The feature which requires the ssl on local host is explained here.
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

In brief, linkedin will send the client a bearer token after the client authorises my app to access their data. The built in javascript library by  linkedin will automatically send this cookie to my server / backend.  This json file info is used for user authentication.

However, linkedin will not send the private cookie if the server is not https.

Comment: Can you clarify why you might need this? I'm not sure how one would benefit from encrypting traffic to their local machine...from their local machine

Comment: I've elaborated. I do also have a domain name pointing to the amazon free tier server. I deployed it with the mup package. Is it worth considering that I develop on the amazon server or is the principle of amazon serving and my localhost serving be the same. ie, no major reconfiguration between local host and another server

Comment: I think this could be of use to you https://gist.github.com/micho/1712812 There is a link to an article on how to setup the self signed ssl in the comments of the gist as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quick and easy solution that works in dev/prod mode, using `http-proxy` ontop of your app.

1) Add in the `tarang:ssl` package

```
meteor add tarang:ssl
```

2) Add your certificate and key to a directory in your app `/private`, e.g `/private/key.pem` and `/private/cert.pem`

Then in your /server code

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    SSLProxy({
       port: 6000, //or 443 (normal port/requires sudo)
       ssl : {
            key: Assets.getText("key.pem"),
            cert: Assets.getText("cert.pem"),

            //Optional CA
            //Assets.getText("ca.pem")
       }
    });
});
```

Then fire up your app and load up `https://localhost:6000`. Be sure not to mix up your ports with https and http as they are served seperately.

With this I'm assuming you know how to create your own self signed certificate, there are loads of resources on how to do this. Just in case here are some links.

- http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

An alternative to self signed certs: it may be better to use an official certificate for your apps domain  and use `/etc/hosts` [to create a loopback on your local computer too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191440/configure-hosts-file-to-use-aliases). This is because its tedious to have to switch certs between dev and prod.

Comment: It would make sense for me to purchase a cert as I will have to at some point. I shall set up the amazon environment and develop on there. I will come back to reference your answer and the meteor package and let you know how I get on. Thank you for the detailed steps.

Comment: I have the package installed and ran "sudo meteor --port https://localhost:443" in the terminal and the application is running perfectly on localhost:443

I have now successfully received the JavaScript API bearer token. Great package!

Comment: Question. What is ca:Assets.getText("ca.pem") correct syntax to include the chain (bundled) certificate? Thank you Akshat

Comment: FYI, port 6000 causes the "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" error in Chrome (and was not working in FF either), so I tried port 3100 and that worked!

Comment: i got a problem here:

events.js:141
W20160901-19:38:18.035(10)? (STDERR)       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
W20160901-19:38:18.035(10)? (STDERR)       ^
W20160901-19:38:18.035(10)? (STDERR) 
W20160901-19:38:18.035(10)? (STDERR) Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443
W20160901-19:38:18.035(10)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
W20160901-19:38:18.036(10)? (STDERR)     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)

Comment: Is this answer still current since node.js now supports SSL? Is there a way to configure meteor to use node directly?

Comment: didn't work for me.
started app with `meteor` command and the app starts in `localhost:3000'. couldn't connect at 'https://localhost:6000'. although it shows `port 6000` is listening to `node` when I check by `netstat`.
Did anyone face the similar problem?

Answer (score 20):

Or you could just use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to port forward :)

1) start your server (i.e. at localhost:3000)

2) start ngrok from command line: ./ngrok http 3000

that should give you http and https urls to access from any device

Comment: does not work for all my workflow. But it's convenient for simple use-case.

Answer (score 7):

Other solution is to use **NGINX**. Following steps are tested on Mac El Capitan, assuming your local website runs on port 3000 :

**1. Add a host to your local machine :**

Edit your host file : `vi /etc/hosts`

Add a line for your local dev domain : `127.0.0.1 dev.yourdomain.com`

Flush your cache `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Now you should be able to reach your local website with http://dev.yourdomain.com:3000

**2. Create a self signed SSL** like explained here : http://mac-blog.org.ua/self-signed-ssl-for-nginx/

**3. Install nginx and configure it** to map https traffic to your local website:

`brew install nginx`

`sudo nginx`

Now you should be able to reach http://localhost:8080 and get an Nginx message.

This is the default conf so now you have to set the https conf :

Edit your conf file :

`vi /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Uncomment the HTTPS server section and change following lines :

`server_name   dev.yourdomain.com;`

Put your certificates you just created :

`ssl_certificate   /path-to-your-keys/nginx.pem;`

`ssl_certificate_key   /path-to-your-keys/nginx.key;`

Change the location section with this one:

```
location / {
          proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
          proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
          proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
          proxy_read_timeout 1800;
          proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        }
```

Restart nginx :

```
 sudo nginx -s stop
 sudo nginx
```

And now you should be able to access https://dev.yourdomain.com

Comment: I've had headaches with this in the past, and this answer worked immediately without modification. Thanks!