# Meteor, docker and SSL on localhost

Tags: ssl, meteor, docker, localhost

Pretty new to docker / docker-machine / docker-compose and use this for a meteor app that needs to connect to a queue and a few other services. I need to setup SSL on localhost as we're using the getUserMedia api (which chrome is deprecating on insecure connections).

I believe I need to create a self signed certificate, but not sure what to do with it after that.  Do I set it up on my local machine? or do I set this up in the docker container?

Note that meteor is actually running in development mode on its container on local

Any definitive help getting started on this would be great.

**EDIT:  while the similar question noted in the comments seems to solve the problem for meteor specifically, I'm interested more importantly in the context of docker and OSX, While my actual problem is with a meteor app currently, I would like to find a solution thats not meteor dependant, but is considerate of the user case.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup (https) SSL on localhost for meteor development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963749/setup-https-ssl-on-localhost-for-meteor-development)

Comment: Hey  - I've seen that, and I do understand that it would solve the problem just for meteor, but I'd like to understand this in the context of docker and OSX.